# How to restrict users from getting entered in a lookup field based on their permission set assignment using validation rules

Tags: custom-object, validation-rule, permission-sets, configuration, lookup-field

I've a use case where Users having a PermissionSetAssignment X should not be allowed to be made owner of a custom object record by another users. I'm able to do this using a trigger but I've to make it work using configuration. How can I achieve this using validation rule or any other config concept (The Lookup field is based on User and Group and lookup filters can't be used here).

Answer (score 0):

Validation rules can reference custom permissions and custom permissions can be assigned to permission sets

so, a rule could look like

```
$Permission.Owner_Change_Restricted
```

where `Owner_Change_Restricted` is a custom permission assigned to a permission set possessed by some users

Personally, I prefer to make my permissions named something positive, so the validation rule would be:

```
NOT($Permission.Owner_Change_Enabled)
```

and custom permission `Owner_Change_Enabled` assigned to permission sets for users that can change ownership.

Comment: Let's suppose we have a user A with Permission Set X and another user B with permission set Y. If user A tries to make user B and owner of a record, he shouldn't be able to do it. Using $Permission in validation rule will reference custom permission of User A and I need to verify Permission of User B when logged in with User A.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your requirement.  To do declaratively, use a before save Flow that does the check and if not valid, sets a checkbox on the object Is_Invalid_Change__c that a Validation Rule can then test and render an appropriate error message. Flow can query the target user and relevant permissionsetassignment object.

Comment: Creating a new field would require design changes and approval. Seems that going through apex is the only way here not to break the existing design and functionalities.

Comment: Best I can come up with for your request for a declarative solution:-)